# Hide/Show element on click JS not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have a simple function when I click on a button to display text for the button, everything is ok but on the first click it's not working then after the second click it's working perfectly can anybody tell me whats my mistake? I have the element hidden in CSS display;none, here is my logic

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
    #myDIV {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="myFunction()">

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>
```

Comment: You never close your button element, so when you show your div the browser includes it as content inside the button.

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"onclick="myFunction()">Правни аспекти на човечки ресурсиn</button>
 Its closed, just didn't copy it properly

Comment: Just add `style="display:none"` to `myDiv`. The first time you look for `x.style.display` there **is no** display style, so it always sets `none`. After that, there **is** a display and it works like you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you didn't close the button tag. So it doesn't find myFunction(). You also need to fetch the computed value of display style not the elements value because css files do not affect the elements styles directly. (e.g. vs style="")

```html
<body>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        if (getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    </script>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
      onclick="myFunction()"
    >
      test
    </button>

    <div id="myDIV">
      This is my DIV element.
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Its closed, still not working on frist click

Comment: The main problem is not the closing, but rather the absense of the attribute `style='display: none`.

Comment: @levche66 I edited my answer. It now shows how to fetch computed styles also